# iOS - get textfield value from another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

in my project i have a viewController composed a **containerView** (which has a tableview with two textfield) and a **button**. Basically, I wish when i press my button, i get the text in the textfield. How can i get the value of the textfield in the viewController if they are contained in a tableview in turn contained in a containerView?

Maybe the image can help figure out:

[image]

Comment: You can achieve it via delegations through protocols.

Comment: no need for that much, he can just pass the value through a property on the second vc